# how to call a resource url running on the same AppEngine instance from a servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have implemented some RESTful resource urls such as http://myapp.appspot.com/temperature/get with Jersey.  I also have a servlet running on the same AppEngine instance with which I want to call the resource urls.  My problem is that I don't know how to refer to the running Appengine instance the servlet is within.  In other words, I'd like to use the AppEngine equivalent of 127.0.0.1 or $SERVER_HOME.

My initial approach was to do something like this, in the servlet:

```
URL url = new URL(getServletContext().getContextPath());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

, but getContextPath() returns an empty string (as it should, since I don't place the application name in the url.

How do I get a reference to the app's base location, so I can reference url resources running within it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not simply have both the restful interface and the rest of the code call the same service code? There's no reason to be making URLFetches to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the URL exists in the same server machine do this:

```
String host = remoteHost;
int port = remotePort;
String remoteContext = //the application root you want to access;
String remtoePath =  // the servlet or path you want to access;
if((host.equals(request.getServerName()) || host.equals("localhost")) 
      && port == request.getServerPort(){
   ....
  ServletContext context = servletContext.get(remoteContext);
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(remotePath);
     //if you want to forward
  //dispatcher.forward(request, response);
     //if you want to include
  //dispatcher.include(request, response);

}
```

Comment: Ramesh: request.getServerName() is what I was looking for. Now it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same instance or the same version of the code? You can't target the same instance. There's no way to do that. You can target the same version (yourdomain.appspot.com or latest.yourdomain.appspot.com). If you want to know if your app is running in the dev server you can use the SystemProperty class

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty

If you want to target a version, you should really know the url... if not, use Ramesh's suggestion. Generally we set up a static properties class in our servlets that hold the name of the currently active domain for this purpose. Or just use TaskQueues... they are great for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, you're right ... I meant same version of the code, not instance. I still need to get used to Google AppEngine semantics/thought patterns, where versioning is rolled into the server runtime environment.

Comment: Then you basically have 3 choices: 1) what ramesh is suggesting, 2) store the location of the app/version in your code or in a config file that's loaded into properties, 3) call a task queue. The task queues are great if this servlet is not for user interaction but rather a 'service' that you need run.